# checking string word does contain digit and does not contain digit

Tags: c++

Let's say I have string sentence "My id is gogo127 and my pin number is 1234"

I want to make it "My id is gogo127 and my pin number is xxxx".

I believe I need to make logic where I check the word contains digit or not and separate it from becoming gogoxxx. Is there way I can do it? by using `#include<string>` and iostream only

Comment: It is somewhat unclear whether you have the text "pin number is" always right before the pin number that you want to cross out. For example, can you have a sentence like 'My pin number is 1234 and my id is gogo127'? Or 'My id is gogo127 and 1234 is my pin number'?

Answer (score 1):

If you are sure that number length will be always 4, you can use below.

```
std::string str = "My id is gogo127 and my pin number is 1234";
std::fill_n(str.rbegin(), 4, 'x');
```

Answer (score 0):

A very broad question that can be answered with "Yes." That's not a particularly useful answer for anyone involved here, so here's a better one.

Start at the end of the `string` and work backwards, replacing each character with an `'X'`, until you find a space.

A reverse iterator from [`std::string::rbegin`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/rbegin) will be very helpful here.